# Have a smaller image then a div stretch to fill the area of the div without image ratio being ruined

Tags: html, css, image

I have a list of images on a page and they are centered in a div 250 px x 175 px. What I want is to have the images increase in size to the div without messing the image's size ratio up, so if the image is 139 x 50 (small banner) it gets wider until it's 250 x 89, and vice versa a 50 x 100 image would scale to be 150x175.

I would prefer to just do it in CSS if possible.

```css
.suppliers-blog-thumbnail .suppliers-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.suppliers-blog-thumbnail:hover .suppliers-overlay {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.suppliers-blog-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 175px;
}

.suppliers-blog-thumbnail .image_center img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 175px;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="suppliers-blog-thumbnail">
  <a target="_blank" class="image_center" href="http://amico-securityproducts.com/lath.htm">
    <img src="http://workspace3.joefoster.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/7b6442_1488bc59e28f439b89b942afef0f7646-mv2.gif">
    <span class="suppliers-overlay">&nbsp;</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean you want the image to fill the div but without losing its quality?

Comment: Just `width:100%` will do.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJKVPR created a code pen of 2 images that are causing issues

Answer (score 0):

Say you have:

```
<div class="wrapper-class">
  <img class="image"/>
  <img class="image"/>
</div>
```

You can have the CSS:

```
.wrapper-class{
  width:275px;
  height:160px;
}
.wrapper-class .image{
  width:100%;
}
```

The catch here is that when the width takes up the entire div's width, the height is automatically adjusted.

Comment: Why aren't you using the OP's source?

Comment: Wanted to simplify it so that if this is the answer, OP can get a clearer insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, `img` `width` set to `100%` and `height` to `auto`.

```css
.suppliers-blog-thumbnail .suppliers-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.suppliers-blog-thumbnail:hover .suppliers-overlay {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.suppliers-blog-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 175px;
}

.suppliers-blog-thumbnail .image_center img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 175px;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="suppliers-blog-thumbnail">
  <a target="_blank" class="image_center" href="http://amico-securityproducts.com/lath.htm">
    <img src="http://workspace3.joefoster.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/7b6442_1488bc59e28f439b89b942afef0f7646-mv2.gif">
    <span class="suppliers-overlay">&nbsp;</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: images with more height then width on the page are still being stretched to match the width of the div

Answer (score 0):

Look my solution for your answer, I hope this is what you mean. If I understand.
Usually for this kind of issues i'm using background-image instead img because of it flexibility.

```css
 .suppliers-blog-thumbnail .suppliers-overlay {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          right: 0px;
          background-color: #1c1c1c;
          bottom: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          opacity: 0;
          filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        }

        .suppliers-blog-thumbnail:hover .suppliers-overlay {
          opacity: 0.4;
        }

        .suppliers-blog-thumbnail {
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
          width: 250px;
          height: 175px;
        }

        .suppliers-blog-thumbnail .image_center img {
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;
          max-height: 175px;
          max-width: 100%;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
        }

        .bg-responsive{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
         }
```

```html
        <div class="suppliers-blog-thumbnail">
          <a target="_blank" class="image_center" href="http://amico-securityproducts.com/lath.htm">
            <div class="bg-responsive" style="background-image: url('http://workspace3.joefoster.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/7b6442_1488bc59e28f439b89b942afef0f7646-mv2.gif');"></div>
            <span class="suppliers-overlay">&nbsp;</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: i tryed your solution but images that are square in size or more height then width are cut off